# Accessing ember cli mirage factory through db in route handlers returns undefined or error

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli-mirage

I have a ember cli mirage factory named activation-code, I can create it inside my tests but when I try to access it in mirage config.js through db that is available in route handlers I get undefined or error, here's my code:

```
  this.get('activation_codes/:id', function(db){
    return {
      data: {
        type: 'activation-code',
        id: db.activation-codes[0].id,
        attributes: db.activation-codes[0]
       }
     };
  });
```

I tried to access it with, db.activationCode/activationCodes/activation-code/activation-codes but I keep getting undefined or error - code/codes is not defined.
When I use regular name like "activation" for factory name I can access it without problems. So, why factory with dasherized name is not working properly and the one named "activation" does?

Answer (score 0):

I find out what the issue was, I'm using ember-cli-mirage version 0.1.11, for this version it was expected that you name your file in snake case and then you can access it with db.factory_name.
From version 0.2 they are following ember-cli convention of dasherized filenames.
http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.2.0-beta.9/upgrading/